# Need all elements of list to be integers

Tags: python, list

I'm currently taking a beginning programming course and need help correcting a function. I need all elements in this list to be integers and not a string. And to do this I need to change one line from the function but I have no idea which line to change! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def read_magic_square(filename):
    """
    Read values from a file into a 2D list

    Parameter:
    filename: the name of the file

    Returns a 2D list of integer values read.
    """

    infile = open(filename, "rt")
    square = []  # start with an empty list

    for line in infile:  # read text from file
        row = []
        numbers = line.split()

        # Loop through the list of numbers.
        # Append each number to the row.
        for num in numbers:
            row.append(num)

        if len(row) > 0:  # Don't count blank lines
            square.append(row)  # Append the row to the 2D list

    return square
```

Comment: `row.append(int(num))`.

Comment: Please make sure your entire code if formatted inside the code block; the first two lines are outside it, making your code harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid errors if there are strings in the line, you can only change the appending line to be *(you can change the `invalid_replacement` to be whatever you want, here I put it as zero)*:

```
invalid_replacement = 0
try:
    row.append(int(num))
except:
    row.append(invalid_replacement)
```